# How to find keywords in multicolumn CSV file using Python 2.7

Tags: python, csv

I'm a newbie so please go easy on me. I have a 100,000 line CSV file (mock_data.csv) in which am searching for keywords from keywords.csv and printing out the lines that contain matches to a new csv file (filename.csv) Based on cobbling together bits of code based on other message threads on stackoverflow, I can accomplish this task if I alter the code to specify which rows to look for keywords using locator.

I have attached new mock data images which should better explain the expected results, which is to return the first 5 rows of the mock_data file (id_number says dummy at the end)

Where I get stuck is that I'm trying to find keywords in any row. I was tinkering with the below lines of code, but didn't get far with it.

```
with open('mock_data.csv', 'r') as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile, delimiter = ',')[enter image description here][1]
    for row in reader:
        found = False
        for keyword in allkeywords:
            if keyword in row:
                found = True
            if found == True:
```

The orginal code I had to look for a keyword in a specified row:

```
import csv
import time
import sys
from collections import defaultdict
import pandas as pd

#import keywords csv (1st col has keyword and 2nd col indicates keyword type)
columns = defaultdict(list)
with open('mock_keywords.csv','r') as f:
   reader = csv.DictReader(map(lambda line:line.lower(),f),delimiter = ',')
   for row in reader:
       for (k,v) in row.items():
           columns[k].append(v)
allkeywords = (columns['keywords'])

timestr = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d-(%h-%M-%s)")
filename = 'output' +str(timestr)+'.csv'

csvout = open(filename, 'wb')
fieldnames =['id_number', 'country', 'cargo_description', 'supplier', 'transport', 'transport_id']
writer = csv.DictWriter(csvout, fieldnames = fieldnames)
writer.writeheader()

with open('mock_data.csv', 'r') as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile, delimiter = ',')
    for row in reader:
        found = False
        for keyword in allkeywords:
            locator = row[2].lower().find(keyword)
            if locator != -1:
                found = True
            if found == True:
                writer.writerow({'id_number':row[0], 'country':row[1], 'cargo_description':row[2], 'supplier':row[3], 'transport':row[4], 'transport_id':row[5]})
csvout.close

#i imagine that when i look for keywords in any part of the csv that writer might write the same row multiple times.
#toclean = pd.read_csv(filename)
#deduped = toclean.drop_duplicates()
#deduped.to_csv(filename)
```

Comment: Can you please post a small snapshot of the data you are working with and the intended outcome? That will help us help you.

Comment: hi, included a screenshot. let me know if you have problem seeing the data. basically, i should get back lines A,C,D,E, and F in the outfile as those lines are the only lines in which keywords are found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. This line of code is wrong, `allkeywords` is **empty**.

   ```
   #Change from  
       allkeywords = (columns['keywords'])
   #to  
       allkeywords = columns.keys()
   ```
2. Don't use binary `'wb'` for csv files

   change to `csvout = open(filename, 'w')`

---

> **Question**: ... I'm trying to find keywords in any row. Where I'm having trouble is that I think I'm getting stuck on converting the lotsofstuff.csv file into lowercase

Why not using DictReader?
You can access all `columns` using header names as `key`.
You can write the whole row at once.

```
for row in csv.DictReader(infile, delimiter = ','):
    if row['id_number'] in allkeywords:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Edit your Questions code accordingly, come back to figure out what you mean with *"trouble ... lowercase"*.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I edited the post to provide more clarity (or so I hope). In the meantime, I have been trying out the above approaches.

Comment: @imstuck: Un indent your `if found == True:` block to the level of the `for...` block. On line `read`and if `True` one line `write`.

Comment: With your help, I think I figured it out. after the line found = False, added below "for field in row". Then in the reader = csv.reader...added lambda function to read the csv in lowercase. That seemed to do it.